# Format Date in ng-Model in Angular Custom Directive for Date Picker

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am a novice in Angular and need help regarding the Custom Directive.
I have a date picker Directive where the user selects Date, Month and Year from a Drop Down which is then displayed in a textbox in the format : YYYY-MM-DD

```
 $scope.$watch('model', function ( newDate ) {
        $scope.dateFields.day = new Date(newDate).getUTCDate();
        $scope.dateFields.month = new Date(newDate).getUTCMonth();
        $scope.dateFields.year = new Date(newDate).getUTCFullYear();
      });
```

The Drop Down is displayed using :

```
<select required name="dateFields.month" data-ng-model="dateFields.month" p ng-options="month.value as month.name for month in months" value="{{dateField.month}}" ng-change="checkDate()" ng-disabled="disableFields"></select>

<select required ng-if="!yearText" name="dateFields.year" data-ng-model="dateFields.year"  ng-options="year for year in years" ng-change="checkDate()" ng-disabled="disableFields"></select>
```

When all above Dropdowns are selected, the Input Textbox shows only the Year whic I want to show the complete date in the Format : YYYY-MM-DD

The Code for that is :

```
<input required ng-if="yearText" type="text" name="dateFields.year" data-ng-model="dateFields.year" placeholder="Year" class="form-control" ng-disabled="disableFields">
```

In the above code there is `data-ng-model="dateFields.year"`. is there any method where I can customize this to show `dateFields.year-dateFields.month-dateFields.date`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest solution is to use dedicated model for complete date. I can see that you are using ngChange directive. In this case you could set proper model value in this function:

```
$scope.checkDate = function() {
    // checking date ...
    // all is fine set full date model
    $scope.dateFields.fullDate = $scope.dateFields.year + '-' + $scope.dateFields.month + '-' + $scope.dateFields.day;
}
```

and use in in HTML:

```
<input data-ng-model="dateFields.fullDate" required ng-if="yearText" type="text" name="dateFields.year" placeholder="Year" class="form-control" ng-disabled="disableFields">
```

I think it should work in your case.

#### Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/SKCbABDifkbnIT2FTV6X?p=preview

Comment: Perfect! This is the exact logic that I was trying and you actually did what I wanted. Thanks a million! That was  indeed helpful. I have ACCEPTED your answer. :D

Comment: Great, I'm glad you figured it out!